# Cannot access page on localhost, ports not working Hyper-V?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyper-v

I have an application that works fine on docker for linux, but when I try to open http://localhost:8080 on Windows I do not see my application.

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.

Do I have to configure something on Hyper-V?

Currently using:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Docker 1.11.1-beta10 (build: 2446)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "localhost" [use "docker" (see item 6)](https://beta.docker.com/docs/windows/getting-started/#step-4-explore-the-application-and-run-examples):

http://docker:8080/